# PHP: simplest way to get the date of the month 6 months prior on the first?

Tags: php, datetime, subtraction

So if today was April 12, 2010
it should return October 1, 2009

Some possible solutions I've googled seem overly complex, any suggestions?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Hm, maybe something like this;

```
echo date("F 1, Y", strtotime("-6 months"));
```

EDIT;

if you would like to specify a custom date use;

```
echo date("F, 1 Y", strtotime("-6 months", strtotime("Feb 2, 2010")));
```

Comment: Other than the comma being in the wrong place in the format string, this looks like the best solution (right now, it'd show "October, 1 2009" instead of "October 1, 2009").

Comment: How would you feed in a custom date to this. i.e. instead of using today, choose Feb 2, 2010

Comment: @stormist, then use; date("F, 1 Y", strtotime("-6 months", strtotime("Feb 2, 2010")));

Comment: @Adnan, don't forget that you could merge those two calls to `strtotime`

Comment: @salathe, excellent point, I can use date("F, 1 Y", strtotime("-6 months Feb 2, 2010")); thank you.

Comment: this still has the taste of slowness with it. parsing strings for dates and stuff. it works and is short, that's for sure

Comment: Caution! This will not always return what you expect, e.g. `date('M d, Y', strtotime("-1 months", strtotime("Dec 31, 2010"))) === 'Dec 01, 2010'`.

Comment: Its not full-proof,

1. echo date("F, 1 Y", strtotime("-6 months", strtotime("2019-10-30")));
=> April, 1 2019

2. echo date("F, 1 Y", strtotime("-6 months", strtotime("2019-10-31")));
=> May, 1 2019

Answer by @knittl works perfectly,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2625498/6080988

Answer (score 11):

A bit hackish but works:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime("-6 months");
$date->modify("-" . ($date->format('j')-1) . " days");
echo $date->format('j, F Y');

?>
```

Comment: Oh, hey, I didn't realized DateTime's constructor accepted -6 months.  I feel stupid now.

Comment: This also works: `new DateTime('first day of this month - 6 months')`

Answer (score 9):

use a combination of [`mktime`](http://php.net/mktime) and [`date`](http://php.net/date):

```
$date_half_a_year_ago = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n')-6, 1, date('y'))
```

to make the new date relative to a given date and not today, call `date` with a second parameter

```
$given_timestamp = getSomeDate();
$date_half_a_year_ago = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n', $given_timestamp)-6, 1, date('y', $given_timestamp))
```

to output it formatted, simply use `date` again:

```
echo date('F j, Y', $date_half_a_year_ago);
```

Comment: I don't have PHP here to test this, but does mktime even accept negative months?  It's documented as returning false for invalid arguments.

Comment: @omg unicorns, yes, from the docs: »mktime() is useful for doing date arithmetic and validation, as it will automatically calculate the correct value for out-of-range input.«

Answer (score 4):

It was discussed in comments but the accepted answer has some unneeded `strtotime()` calls.  Can be simplified to:

```
date("F 1, Y", strtotime("Feb 2, 2010 - 6 months"));
```

Also, you can use `DateTime()` like this which I think is equally as readable:

```
(new DateTime('Feb 2, 2010'))->modify('-6 months')->format('M 1, Y');
```

Or using static method....

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('M j, Y','Feb 2, 2010')
    ->modify('-6 months')
    ->format('M 1, Y');
```

Comment: Thank you, which method is faster?